# what does it mean when there are two brackets in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem that I don't under because I don't know what the answer is because there are two lots of brackets in D
B n D
when B = {6,7,8,9}
when D = {{6,7},6,4}

Answer (score 2):

$B\cap D=\{6\}$

Because in B are the elements 6,7,8 and 9.
To D belongs the elements $\{6,7\}$,6 and 4.

Note that in the set D is the additional set $\{6,7\}$ as an element. Do not misunderstand that with the set $D'=\{6,7,6,4\}=\{6,7,4\}$

The intersect of two sets contains all elements which are in both sets. And this is only the 6.

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: yes i think so, so in set D you ignore the first 6 and the 7

Comment: Ignore is maybe a wrong word for it. It is simply that the set \{6,7\} is an element of D. You have to view this as one object. You could write $D=\{A,6,4\}$ where $A=\{6,7\}$. And the element A is not in B.

Answer (score 1):

it means that the element of a set is again a set, hence in your case the elements of $D$ are numbers $6, 4$ and a set consisting of $6$ and $7$hence $\{6,7\}$

Comment: whats the answer then

Comment: well, what are the common elements of $B$ and $D$ based on what I said?

Comment: the common elements are 6,7

Comment: $7$ is not an element of $D$, a _set_ $\{6,7\}$ is an element of $D$ but that's a totaly different object

Comment: so the answer is 6 then

Comment: yup, the answer is in fact $\{6\}$ because $6$ is the only common element, hence the _set_ of common elements is the set $\{6\}$